# A question regarding "might have been"

Tags: grammar, tense

Dear fellow learners and teachers,
When I was going through a book a sentence caught my eye, and it goes like this:

> *I guess it might have been Jasmine who stole that necklace.*

The question is, can I also use 'might have been J who has stolen that necklace'? Are the two tenses interchangeable?

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: I would only say "it might *be*" with "has stolen".

Comment: @LukeSawczak What if you were referring to it in the past?

Comment: "It might have been Jasmine who has stolen that necklace" — mismatch of tenses. "It might be Jasmine who stole that necklace" — fine.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I disagree. I think you can use either. I have never heard anything like that at all. Just like most uses of one or the other.

Comment: It might have been Jasmine [in the past] the person who has stolen the necklace [as I say this now in the present. ]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the past tense is more likely.  The present perfect is a present tense and so is about the current state.  That would normally be used with a present tense modal phrase

> Jo has stolen the necklace

This tells us about Jo now; she "has" the "experience of stealing" in her past.

> I might be Jo who has stolen the necklace.

There is no real need for the present perfect here, and most people would use the past tense in this particular situation.  But models don't have past tense.
The perfect structure is also used with models to talk about the past. That would go naturally with a past tense.

> It might have been Jo who stole the necklace.

Here we are speculating about the past.

Comment: You have some typos in your answer, just wanted to let you know (^_^)/

Answer (score -1):

Might be is a modal used in the present for possibility; in the sample sentences about another clause in the past.

She *might be* busy so let's not bother her. [present]
She *might be* the one who stole the necklace. [said in the present time about a past event: simple past, finished]
She **might be** the one who has stolen the necklace. [**when** not determined but signals the past]

Yesterday: She *might have been busy; that is why she *didn't talk* to me*.     **past tense.**

- I guess it *might have been* Jasmine who *stole* that necklace. [past tense for stole and might have been. two days ago, last night, last week, any of those adverbials could implied; the action is over]
- I guess it *might have been Jasmine* who has *stolen* the necklace. [past tense might have been plus present perfect that signals the past but not when, as of the present time]